# Weird errors while animating (Adreno, GL)

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-animation

I have two weird errors which sometimes appear when I animate my Views (with a little help of NineOldAndroids). It's hard to debug so I'm not sure yet, but I think it may be caused by `v.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);`. And there are some drawing issues which go together with this log, but they are not consistent.

These are the errors (both evoked in different activities):

`<gl_draw_error_checks:437>: Error: Unknown: 0x506`

`<qgl2DrvAPI_glStartTilingQCOM:162>: GL_INVALID_VALUE`

Both come with Tag `Adreno200-ES20`. Seems like an OpenGL issue, but I don't know what may be causing it and what to do to get rid of it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Unfortunately not. If I remember correctly something made me think that the error might be device specific. I tested on Htc One S, and you?

Comment: I would really like to know if someone had a similar problem on a phone other than htc

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting

```
<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Doesn't help, already tried that. Plus I need hardware acceleratio on this